How to verify ValidateRefreshToken is called within RefreshTokenForUser in ASP.NET Core API unit test (NUnit)?
I'm writing unit tests for an ASP.NET Core API using NUnit. I have an interface IJwtManagerRepository with methods RefreshTokenForUser and ValidateRefreshToken.  In RefreshTokenForUser, the actual implementation calls ValidateRefreshToken with potentially null arguments.
public interface IJwtManagerRepository
{
    Task<(bool Success, string ErrorMessage, int ErrorCode)> RefreshTokenForUser(Account user, string refreshToken);
    Task<(bool Success, string ErrorMessage, int ErrorCode, bool IsExpired, RefreshToken RefreshTokenInDatabase)> ValidateRefreshToken(Account user, string refreshToken);
}

public class JwtManagerRepository : IJwtManagerRepository
{

private readonly WebApplicationFactory<Program> WebApplicationFactory;

public IJwtManagerRepository IJwtManagerRepository { get; set; }

    public async Task<(bool Success, string ErrorMessage, int ErrorCode)> RefreshTokenForUser(Account user, string refreshToken)
    {
        await ValidateRefreshToken(null, null); // Potentially null arguments
    }

    // Implementation of ValidateRefreshToken omitted
}

// Test Code (incomplete)
public class IJwtManagerRepositoryTests : IClassFixture<WebApplicationFactory<Program>>
{
    public IJwtManagerRepositoryTests(WebApplicationFactory<Program> webApplicationFactory)
{
    WebApplicationFactory = webApplicationFactory;
    var scope = WebApplicationFactory.Services.CreateScope();
    IJwtManagerRepository = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IJwtManagerRepository>();
} 

    [Fact]
    public async Task RevokeRefreshToken_Calls_ValidateRefreshToken()
    {
        // Arrange
        var account = await GetAccount(); // Replace with your logic to obtain account
        var refreshToken = ""; // Replace with actual refresh token

        await IJwtManagerRepository.RefreshTokenForUser(account, refreshToken);

        // How to verify ValidateRefreshToken was called?
    }

}
My question is: How can I verify within the test that the ValidateRefreshToken method is actually called when RefreshTokenForUser is executed?

To verify ValidateRefreshToken is called within RefreshTokenForUser duriing test(NUnit) you could use the Mocking technique. that will allow you to create the mock object taht with act like complex real object and monitor interactions with them. NUnit itself doesn't include a built-in mocking library, so you'll need to add Moq or another mocking library to your project.
Install  Moq package.
Here is the sample code using the Moq:
using Moq;
using NUnit.Framework;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class IJwtManagerRepositoryTests : IClassFixture<WebApplicationFactory<Program>>
{
    private readonly WebApplicationFactory<Program> WebApplicationFactory;
    private Mock<IJwtManagerRepository> mockJwtManagerRepository;

    public IJwtManagerRepositoryTests(WebApplicationFactory<Program> webApplicationFactory)
    {
        WebApplicationFactory = webApplicationFactory;
        mockJwtManagerRepository = new Mock<IJwtManagerRepository>();
    } 

    [Test]
    public async Task RefreshTokenForUser_Calls_ValidateRefreshToken()
    {
        var account = await GetAccount(); 
        var refreshToken = "some_refresh_token";
        
 
        mockJwtManagerRepository.Setup(repo => repo.ValidateRefreshToken(null, null))
                                .ReturnsAsync((true, "", 0, false, new RefreshToken()));

          await mockJwtManagerRepository.Object.RefreshTokenForUser(account, refreshToken);
        mockJwtManagerRepository.Verify(repo => repo.ValidateRefreshToken(null, null), Times.Once());
    }
}


The IJwtManagerRepository need to be from scope.ServiceProvider.GetService(), because actual interface implement is from WebApplicationFactory not from Mocking

@user2877989 Testing  method was called within another method of the same class, especially when using real implementations rather than mocks, bit complex without using mocking.  your implementation uses WebApplicationFactory<Program> for integration testing and you're obtaining the instance of IJwtManagerRepository from the application's service container, direct method call verification like you might do with a mocking framework such as Moq is not straightforward. because of that I have suggested way by using moq. let me know if you have still any concern.
